# Launcher App will not read NFC after restart

Tags: android, flutter, nfc

I have a strange problem and need some help. I have developed and Flutter app, which reads NFC chips. The app is a work time tracking app, which should run 7*24. After some days 7 -14 the app is automatically closed by Android OS, which is really painful. If an employee, next day will then check in and only see Android OS. So I have two questions. Is there any solution to run App 7/24 all the time?

I tried then a new approach and changed the app to a launcher app and also set this in the settings. That means, if I navigate back or tap task manager all the time, the user will navigate back to my app. But here I have the problem, that after plugin electricity the app will not ready any NFC. It shows me, that there is no application which supports NFC.

Following in AndoridManifest.xml

```xml
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
```

I used this package as NFC reader.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nfc_kit

Comment: Creating a launcher, just for running an app in background is very bad design. Instead you should try using a native service. Also, android pauses an app from background if an app is not used for a long time. You could try disabling battery optimization for your app. Also, use a native service to run in background indefinetly.

Comment: I tried with some background job, which runs all 15 min and the app will then also be closed after some days

Comment: Then try using a foreground service. It's only problem is that it will always show notification, but the foreground service is guaranteed to run without being killed by the os.

Comment: Sorry I can't follow 100%. What you mean with foreground service? Is there any flutter package for that?. What should the foreground service do? I'm a bit lost on Android.

Comment: I now created an background service with this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service The service is really stupid and sending current date time to app. I hope that will fix the problem. Because my problem is, that the app should run 7x24 and not be stopped, I also was thinking that Wake lock can also solve the problem, but then we have display all the time running. About battery, we don't need to think, because the device has no battery and is connected directly via electricity.

Comment: Background Services can be killed anytime by the OS to free up ram on device but foreground services get the privilege of being run even when ram is low on device. See: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Comment: Also see this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task